# SparseCategoricalCrossentropy.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument using Streamlit /Python

Tags: streamlit

I am classifying images using Streamlit and Python. I am getting an error: `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_class'`.

```
TypeError: SparseCategoricalCrossentropy.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_class'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Gradio\flask and htm\project-folder\backend\org.py", line 18, in <module>
    model = load_model()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\legacy_caching\caching.py", line 625, in wrapped_func
    return get_or_create_cached_value()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\legacy_caching\caching.py", line 609, in get_or_create_cached_value
    return_value = non_optional_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Gradio\flask and htm\project-folder\backend\org.py", line 8, in load_model
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/my_model.h5')
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 153, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
```

This is my code.

```py
import streamlit as st
import tensorflow as tf

st.set_option('deprecation.showfileUploaderEncoding', False)
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def load_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/my_model.h5')
    return model

    
    
model = load_model()
st.write("""
        # Image Classification App
        """
    
    )

file = st.file_uploader("Please upload an image", type=["jpg", "png"])
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

def import_and_predict(image_data, model):
    
    size = (180,180)
    image =ImageOps.fit(image_data, size, Image.LANCZOS)
    img =np.asarray(image)
    img_reshape = img[np.newaxis,...]
    prediction = model.predict(img_reshape)
    
    return prediction

if file is None:
    st.text("Please upload an image file")
    
else:
    image = Image.open(file)
    st.image(image, use_column_width=True)
    predictions = import_and_predict(image, model)
    class_names = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse']
    string = "This image most likely is a :" +class_names[np.argmax(predictions)]
    st.success(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the model with `compile=False`. This may also be due to a version mismatch.

Try it out,

```py
def load_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/my_model.h5', compile=False)
    return model
```

It will load the model only for inference. If you still face issues then it may be a version conflict. The model was saved in a different version of TensorFlow.